# Use html generated by other controllers as part of the returned page in Spring

Tags: spring, controller

In my webapp I have a page which presents a number of tabs, each of which must be independently reloadable via AJAX. For user experience's sake, I want all the data to be presented immediately when the page loads instead of ajaxing it in. For maintainability' s sake(and because I'm lazy) i don't want to write separate code for the complete page.

Is there a way to include the html that would be generated by calls to other controllers in the page?

I use jsp for views if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way of doing this would be to manually trigger an AJAX call for each tab at page load event. This will bring the HTML for each tab. The downside of doing this would be that it'll cost you X requests.

Another option would be to create a Front Controller for all others that send the info per tab. You send one request to the front controller and its job would be to put the results of the others together and give a single big response.

Comment: The FrontController thing is exactly what i'm trying to accomplish. The question is how to do it without writing code for combining all the ModelAndViews together.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to automate this kind of interaction between controllers. You could try and search about "controller chaining in Spring" which basically involves passing responsability between controllers. I'm not sure how helpful this is in your situation.